# How to switch gridpaglayout panel on a jframe

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I have a jframe, and 4 jpanel with gridbaglayout. I want to switch from a jpanel to another with a click on a button. But instead of getting the first panel, I get the last one. 
Here's what I did :

```
public static void main(String args[]){

        JFrame myframe = new JFrame();

        try {
            contentPane = new BackgroundPanel();
            contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            contentPane.setBounds(0, 0, myframe.getWidth(), myframe.getHeight());
            //principalpane.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            principalpane = new BackgroundPanel();
            principalpane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            principalpane.setBounds(0, 0, myframe.getWidth(), myframe.getHeight());
            //principalpane.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            optionspane = new BackgroundPanel();
            optionspane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            optionspane.setBounds(0, 0, myframe.getWidth(), myframe.getHeight());
            //principalpane.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            datapane = new BackgroundPanel();
            datapane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            datapane.setBounds(0, 0, myframe.getWidth(), myframe.getHeight());
            //principalpane.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            genpane = new BackgroundPanel();
            genpane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            genpane.setBounds(0, 0, myframe.getWidth(), myframe.getHeight());
            //principalpane.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /***************************************************************************/
        /*****************************First*****************************************/
        GridBagConstraints gbc=new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagConstraints gbcl=new GridBagConstraints();
        JLabel welcome=new JLabel("Optimizing & Visualizing Process Progression");
        welcome.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        gbcl.gridx=0;
        gbcl.gridy=0;
        gbcl.gridwidth = 2;
        gbcl.gridheight=1;
        gbcl.insets=new Insets(10,200,5,100);
        gbcl.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        principalpane.add(welcome, gbcl);


        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
    //  gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets=new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        try {
            principalpane.add(Mypanel.secondpane(), gbc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        gbc.gridx=1;
        gbc.gridy=1;

    //  gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
        gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets=new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        try {
            principalpane.add(Mypanel.firstpanel(), gbc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=2;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridheight=2;
    //  gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets=new Insets(0,10,5,10);
        try {
            principalpane.add(Mypanel.thirdpanel(), gbc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /******************Second ***************************/
        GridBagConstraints ogbc=new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagConstraints ogbcl=new GridBagConstraints();

        JLabel optwelcome=new JLabel("Abnormal Process Progression");
        optwelcome.setFont(new Font("Ubuntu", Font.BOLD, 16));
        ogbcl.gridx=0;
        ogbcl.gridy=0;
        ogbcl.gridwidth = 2;
        ogbcl.gridheight=1;
        ogbcl.insets=new Insets(10,280,5,10);
        ogbcl.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        optionspane.add(optwelcome, ogbcl);

        gbc.gridx=0;
        ogbc.gridy=1;
        ogbc.weightx = 1;
        ogbc.weighty = 1;
    //  gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        ogbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        ogbc.insets=new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        try {
            optionspane.add(Mypanel.forthpanel(), ogbc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ogbc.gridx=1;
        ogbc.gridy=1;
        ogbc.weightx = 1;
        ogbc.weighty = 1;
        ogbcl.gridwidth = 1;
        ogbc.gridheight=2;
    //  gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        ogbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        ogbc.insets=new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        try {
            optionspane.add(Mypanel.sixthpanel(), ogbc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ogbc.gridx=0;
        ogbc.gridy=2;
        ogbc.weightx = 1;
        ogbc.weighty = 1;
        ogbc.gridheight=1;
    //  gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        ogbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        ogbc.insets=new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        try {
            optionspane.add(Mypanel.fifthpanel(), ogbc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ogbc.gridx=0;
        ogbc.gridy=3;
        ogbc.weightx = 1;
        ogbc.weighty = 1;
        ogbc.gridwidth=2;
    //  gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        ogbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        ogbc.insets=new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        try {
            optionspane.add(Mypanel.seventhpanel(), ogbc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*************************Third*************************************/
        GridBagConstraints dgbc=new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagConstraints dgbcl=new GridBagConstraints();

        JLabel datawelcome=new JLabel("Please Enter the QoS' values");
        datawelcome.setFont(new Font("Ubuntu", Font.BOLD, 16));
        dgbcl.gridx=0;
        dgbcl.gridy=0;
        dgbcl.gridwidth = 1;
        dgbcl.gridheight=1;
        dgbcl.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        dgbcl.insets=new Insets(0,250,35,10);
        dgbcl.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        datapane.add(datawelcome, dgbcl);


        dgbc.gridx=0;
        dgbc.gridy=0;
        dgbc.weightx = 1;
        dgbc.weighty = 1;
        dgbcl.anchor=GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        dgbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        dgbc.insets=new Insets(5,10,10,5);
        try {
            datapane.add(Mypanel.eighthpanel(), dgbc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        dgbc.gridx=0;
        dgbc.gridy=1;
        gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        dgbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        dgbc.insets=new Insets(5,0,5,5);
        try {
            datapane.add(Mypanel.ninethpanel(), dgbc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    /****************Fourth*************************************/
        GridBagConstraints ggbc=new GridBagConstraints();

        ggbc.gridx=0;
        ggbc.gridy=0;
        ggbc.weightx = 1;
        ggbc.weighty = 1;
        ggbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        ggbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        ggbc.insets=new Insets(5,10,10,5);
        try {
            genpane.add(Mypanel.tenthpanel(), ggbc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ggbc.gridx=0;
        ggbc.gridy=1;
        ggbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        ggbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        ggbc.insets=new Insets(5,0,5,5);
        try {
            genpane.add(Mypanel.eleventhpanel(), ggbc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        GridBagConstraints cgbc=new GridBagConstraints();

        cgbc.gridx=0;
        cgbc.gridy=0;
        cgbc.weightx = 1;
        cgbc.weighty = 1;
        cgbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        cgbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        principalpane.setVisible(true);
        contentPane.add(principalpane, cgbc);

        cgbc.gridx=0;
        cgbc.gridy=0;
        cgbc.weightx = 1;
        cgbc.weighty = 1;
        cgbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        cgbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        optionspane.setVisible(false);
        contentPane.add(optionspane, cgbc);

        cgbc.gridx=0;
        cgbc.gridy=0;
        cgbc.weightx = 1;
        cgbc.weighty = 1;
        cgbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        cgbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        datapane.setVisible(false);
        contentPane.add(datapane, cgbc);

        cgbc.gridx=0;
        cgbc.gridy=0;
        cgbc.weightx = 1;
        cgbc.weighty = 1;
        cgbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        cgbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        genpane.setVisible(false);
        contentPane.add(genpane, cgbc);

        contentPane.setVisible(true);
        myframe.getContentPane().add(contentPane);

        myframe.pack();
        myframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        myframe.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

        myframe.setVisible(true);
        myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
```

Comment: Too hard to read. can you  post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Use Card Layout `#CardLayout`

Comment: Yes, it worked with cardlayout.

Comment: @Imanopholist, Don't forget to "accept" the answer. by clicking the check mark. so other know the problem has been solved. Also don't forget to "accept" answers in all your other questions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much code to understand what you are doing but a GridBagLayout is used for static layouts where the components don't dynamically change.

> I want to switch from a jpanel to another with a click on a button.

Sound to me like you should be using a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) which will only display one panel at a time and allow your to swap panels are required.

The tutorial example shows how to swap panels when an ActionEvent is generated.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'll do, but my stupid mistake was that I forgot to delete extends from my class, so instead of showing my class interface, it shows another one.